# Background image shows a black bottom bar when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, image, background, android-softkeyboard

I have an android application in which i want to enter a password  and if it is correct then go to the new activity. For this i showed a custom dialog with an EditText field.If the password is correct then hide kayboard and go to next activity.I used following code for hiding keyboard

```
    alertBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              //start new acivity for result
         }
        }).start();

    }
});
```

And load next activity  using **startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)** inside a thread in onClick of OK button of the dialog.But before loading next actvity,after hiding keyboard the background image shows a black bottom bar like [image: this]

When back to this Activity the background image displays like this for a moment.
I tried **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);** and set **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** for this activity in the manifest file. It does not work for me.What is the problem here and how too fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing the keyboard, wait a small delay with a runnable to give the background of your Activity a moment to repaint.

Use a `Handler` to wait the small delay and return to the UI thread.

**Add this to your class**:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

**Define a Runnable**:

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode);
    }
};
```

**Update your code**:

```
alertBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

        // Wait a moment and jump to the next activity.
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: See if the updated Handler with an actual delay works for you.

Comment: Exactly i did not want  a delay there.Because of this I used a thread for starting new activity

Comment: Is it possible to make the layout  normal  after hiding keyboard using something like layout.invalidate()?